# HostGator: Sent JSON data from Server using cgi python script

Tags: python, json, server, cgi

I am trying to implement some script that deliver json data on client based on different client-requests. 
So far, I am able to deliver html data usin python script. For exmaple, this script works just fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print("Content-Type: text/html\n\n")  # html markup follows
print("""
<html>
  <Title>Hello in HTML</Title>
<body>
  <p>Hello There!</p>
  <p><b>Hi There!</b></p>  
</body>
</html> """)
```

Now I wanted to test a python script which delivers json data:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys, json

jsonData = {"success": "true"})

print('Content-Type: application/json\n\n')
print (json.dumps(jsonData))
```

I have set right permissions to 755, but still I get as respons error 500.

Same example in my localhost is working just fine. Also, If I connect to the server using ssh and execute the python script, it works and I get this outpot:

```
Content-Type: application/json


{"success": "true"}
```

As much as I read, there are some issues with cross-origin, but I dont get correctly, how could something like this activated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the status code & content-length in the CGI

**Try**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys, json

jsonData = {"success": "true"})
jsonData = json.dumps(jsonData)
print "Status: 200 OK"
print "Content-Type: application/json"
print "Length:", len(jsonData)
print jsonData
```